# Using deltaTime and Frame Rate Independence

Tags: libgdx

I'm working on one of my first games and I've read that linking your game logic to FPS is bad because it will run differently at different FPS (obviously). 
I have already made some of the basic game dependent on frame rate and now that I know this, I would like to unlink the logic and render. I've learned that LibGdx has deltaTime in its render method for this, however I believe I'm misunderstanding how I am to use it.

For example, my movement currently looks something like this:

```
if (rightKeyisPressed)
    setVelocityX(movementSpeeD)
playerPos.add(getVelocity)
```

In my case, I would like the player to move 6 units per second. Since I built this on 60 fps, that means that movementSpeed is 0.1. Now the way I have seen deltaTime used is by scaling the movementSpeed based on the time like this:

```
setVelocityX(movementSpeed * deltaTime)
```

However, now I move very slow because delteTime is a very small number. How can I make movement still the same speed without depending on the fps?
Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I just can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because movementSpeed should be how many units you would like your character to move *per second (so your movement speed should be 6, for 6 units per second)*, and multiplying that by deltaTime in LibGDX will give you a value that will achieve the movement of *movementSpeed* per second.  Delta times work differently depending upon how they are implemented, and in LibGDX this is how the default way is done, I hope this all made sense - I can elaborate more if needed, I hope I understood your question.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that I need to change thing to a per second measurement.